# Is this how you prove by induction for inequalities?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, induction

the question is here: http://cpsc.ualr.edu/srini/DM/chapters/examples/ex2.3.2.html

My solution is as below:

[image: The confusion is in the logic in the second last line]

Comment: I don't get it sorry, I added 2k + 1 on both sides. is there something wrong with that? I'm basically asking if this is the way to do a proof by induction

Comment: Is the logic for the second last statement correct?

Comment: I get what you are saying I think, we have to follow k+1 from k, but what i have figured out from this induction in inequalities parts, I just wanna know if the comparing of sides and arriving to conclusion is fine. Here is another sum I did https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/1374858_620062448058200_1310443846_n.jpg

Comment: @abiessu I really don't see what is wrong with his proof. He is saying the following: By $P(k)$ we have $$k^2 \geq 2k+3 \,.$$Adding $2k+1$ on both sides you get $$(k+1)^2 \geq 4k+4 \,.$$ Now, observing that $4k+4 > 2k+5$ finishes the proof. It is a direct proof, start at $P(k)$ and get $P(k+1)$.

Comment: @abiessu The proof shows that $$(k+1)^2 \geq 4k+4 > 2k+5 \,.$$ Which part is wrong? You are arguing that $(k+1)^2 \geq 4k+4$ is not the same thing as $(k+1)^2 \geq 2k+5$, he never said they are.

Comment: @abiessu No is not. To prove $P(k+1)$ you have to START at $P(k)$ and obtain $P(k+1)$. That is what induction is. Reducing $P(k+1)$ to $P(k)$ is what we usually do, but if you do this you have to make sure that all implications are going BACKWARDS, this already tells you you are going the wrong way [we only do this because it is typically easier.]

Comment: @abiessu The inductive step is $P(k) \Rightarrow P(k+1)$. Which means use $P(k)$ to prove $P(k+1)$. This is EXACTLY what he did, he started at $P(k)$ and proved that $P(k+1)$ is right.... You argue that this method works in this case but it might not work in a different situation, but this doesn't make the solution wrong.... Actually this direct proof is the formal mathematical way of writing an induction proof, reducing $P(k+1)$ to $P(k)$ is less formal, as the implications are not always equivalences.

Comment: @N.S.: I see what you mean.  To all: I respectfully retract my foolishness.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is valid. One thing to keep in mind is that though Induction solves the problem, it does so only for integers. A much simpler proof, would be $$ n^2 \ge 3n \ge 2n + 3 $$
Also, make sure you keep a distinction between what you want to prove, and what you already know. An better layout would be as such:

The base case: $3^2 \ge 2(3) + 3$

The inductive step: Suppose $k^2 \ge 2k + 3$. Adding $2k + 1$ to both sides gives $$k^2+ 2k + 1 \ge 4k+4 $$ We know $4k + 4 \ge 2k + 10 \ge 2(k+1) + 3$, so $$ (k+1)^2 \ge 4k + 4 \ge 2(k+1) + 3 $$which completes our inductive step.

Comment: I changed all $n$s to $k$s. And I can't make sense of your last statement.

Comment: Yes, I had showed that if $k^2 \ge 2k + 3$, we have $(k+1)^2 \ge 2(k+1) + 3$, by adding $2n + 1$ to both sides..

Comment: what? I said $4k+4\ge 2j+10\ge 2(k+1)+3$..

Comment: What does this mean: 'By assumption, k≥3, therefore the statement to be proved is true.' when k >= 2?

Comment: @abiessu If he proves that $A >C$ and $C>B$ that is a right proof that $A >B$. You are arguing that $A>C$ is not equivalent to $A>B$, but to prove something it suffices to prove something stronger.

Comment: @abiessu But why correct something which is right? Especially in problems with inequalities, going the other way you suggest is not always right. This direct method is usually harder/longer but it is always correct. The reduction of $P(k+1)$ to $P(k)$ is typically easier, but you have to make sure that all implications you do on the way are equivalences. That method might be easier, but sometimes students don't realize that we are in a case where the backwards reduction method doesn't work, they just use it because it is easier. The methodology used here is actually the formally correct one...

Comment: @abiessu He did that, if you read carefully the paper he sais "We have to prove $(k+1)^2 \geq 2(k+1)+3$...The point is that this is the goal, he should not be using this, he needs to start at $P(k)$ and obtain this statement.... So, he started at $P(k)$ added $2k+1$ on both sides and obtained after some simplifications $$(k+1)^2 \geq 4k+4 >2(k+1)+3$$ which is exactly $P(k+1)$... Start at $P(k)$ and obtain $P(k+1)$ is exactly what induction is ...

Comment: I take back my previous statements, I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Prove true for $n = k + 1$.

$${(k + 1)}^2 \ge 2(k + 1) + 3.......a$$

Taking the $LHS$ of inequality $a$ you end up with

$${(k + 1)}^2 = k^2 + 2k + 1......(1)$$

Using the assumption, $k^2 \ge 2k +3$, $(1)$ becomes, $${(k + 1)}^2 = k^2 + 2k + 1 \ge (2k + 3) + 2k + 1 (\forall n \ge 3)$$

$${(k + 1)}^2 \ge (2k + 3) + 2k + 1.........b$$

Taking the RHS of inequality $b$,
$$(2k + 3) + 2k + 1 = 4k + 4 = 4k + 1 + 3 = 2 \cdot 2k + 1 + 3$$

$$2 \cdot 2k + 1 + 3 \ge 2(k + 1) + 3 (\forall n \ge 3)$$

Therefore $${(k + 1)}^2 \ge 2(k + 1) + 3 (\forall n \ge 3)$$

Comment: Didnt realize...but I did not add $2k + 1$ to both sides, I used the assumption and replaced $k^2$? Would it not follow that if $k^2 \ge 2k + 3$ that $k^2 +2k + 1 \ge (2k + 3) + 2k + 1$?

Comment: @abiessu I see what you were saying, I added a restriction (more like forgot it), would it then be okay?

Comment: Okay. But this is how I learned how to do it...Which is to write out the whole  formula in terms of $k + 1$, break off the $n = k$ part and then replace it with the assumption made about $n = k$. Then through manipulation you rearrange things so that you are left with the right-hand side in terms of $k + 1$.

Comment: @abiessu I think you misconstrued my wording, I think this is less ambiguous?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion.  Your method is correct after all.